# I want to execute my custom facts which I made it in facter

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise, facter

```
# hardware_platform.rb

Facter.add('hardware_platform') do
  setcode do
    Facter::Core::Execution.exec('/bin/uname --hardware-platform')
  end
end
```

I want to execute it and when I gave `facter --puppet`. This information is not coming in the facter log. Tell me how to get the information from facts

Comment: You would need to put some effort into providing precise details of what you already tried, the documentation you already read and so forth.

Comment: Is this fact part of a puppet module?

Answer (score 1):

> Facter offers multiple methods of loading facts:
>
> 1. $LOAD_PATH, or the Ruby library load path
> 2. The --custom-dir command line option
> 3. The environment variable ‘FACTERLIB’
>
> You can use these methods to do things like test files locally before distributing them, or you can arrange to have a specific set of facts available on certain machines.

**Using the Ruby load path**

Facter searches all directories in the Ruby `$LOAD_PATH` variable for subdirectories named facter, and loads all Ruby files in those directories. If you had a directory in your `$LOAD_PATH` like `~/lib/ruby`, set up like this:

```
#~/lib/ruby
  └── facter
      ├── rackspace.rb
      ├── system_load.rb
      └── users.rb
```

Facter loads `facter/system\_load.rb`, `facter/users.rb`, and `facter/rackspace.rb`.

**Using the `--custom-dir` command line option**

Facter can take multiple `--custom-dir` options on the command line that specifies a single directory to search for custom facts. Facter attempts to load all Ruby files in the specified directories. This allows you to do something like this:

```
$ ls my_facts
system_load.rb
$ ls my_other_facts
users.rb
$ facter --custom-dir=./my_facts --custom-dir=./my_other_facts system_load users
system_load => 0.25
users => thomas,pat
```

**Using the `FACTERLIB` environment variable**

Facter also checks the environment variable `FACTERLIB` for a delimited (semicolon for Windows and colon for all other platforms) set of directories, and tries to load all Ruby files in those directories. This allows you to do something like this:

```
$ ls my_facts
system_load.rb
$ ls my_other_facts
users.rb
$ export FACTERLIB="./my_facts:./my_other_facts"
$ facter system_load users
system_load => 0.25
users => thomas,pat
```

Source: https://docs.puppet.com/facter/3.6/custom_facts.html#loading-custom-facts